# How Can I Stop Newline at the Very End of a Loop?

Tags: c, loops, newline

I have a programming assignment for class where the output must match exactly the contents of a file. For the problem, I have to use a loop that will continuously print out values with a specified format. My problem is stopping the last newline character from occurring when the loop is completed.

Because of class policies, I can not include my actual code or the end goal that I am trying to accomplish, but let's say I am trying to print out the factorial of a number using a for-loop. I want to have the answers separated by line EXCEPT I don't want the last one to start a new line under it. How can I solve this problem without stopping the new early or having to create another loop afterwards?

```
int count; 
int number; // some random value
int sum = 1;

for(count = 1; count <= number; count++)
{
  sum *= count;
  printf("Current Sum: %d\n", sum);
}
```

Let's say the number is 3.
I expect the output:

```
Current Sum: 1
Current Sum: 2
Current Sum: 6 //ends here, no newline
```

However, I get:

```
Current Sum: 1
Current Sum: 2
Current Sum: 6
               //new line that I don't want
```

Comment: What happens if you output the newline at the beginning of the loop instead of the end? Maybe a simple `putchar ('\n');`?

Comment: Extremely evil, but works: `printf("Current Sum: %d%s", sum, &"\n"[count>=number]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply leave that case (last line) out of the loop

```
for(count = 1; count < number; count++)
{
  sum *= count;
  printf("Current Sum: %d\n", sum);
}
sum *= count;
printf("Current Sum: %d", sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int count; 
int number; // some random value
int sum = 1;

for(count = 1; count <= number; count++)
{
  sum *= count;
  printf("Current Sum: %d", sum);
  if(count+1 <= number)
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is the quickest and easiest way to solve this problem I can currently think of.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach to this problem is to treat the first case as a special one rather than the last case.  Since there's always a first case, this is actually simpler.

```
int count; 
int number; // some random value
int sum = 1;

printf("Current Sum: %d", sum);
for (count = 2; count <= number; count++) {
  sum *= count;
  printf("\nCurrent Sum: %d", sum);
}
```

[Why is it called "`sum`" when it's actually a product?  What do you want to happen when `number` is 0 or negative?]

Comment: You're right. It should be product, and that is also a good test case to consider. However, I was just using the first example I had that came to mind since I am not to disclose the contents of my course to online resources. I just needed proper guidance for correcting this issue in the future if it were to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

it's because `printf("Current Sum: %d\n", sum)` , you generate new line every loop. When using count <= number, my answer below:

```
int count; 
int number; // sum random value
int sum = 1;

for(count = 1; count <= number; count++)
{
  sum *= count;
  printf("Current Sum: %d", sum);
  if(count!=number){
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

But if you are using count < number :

```
int count; 
int number; // sum random value
int sum = 1;

for(count = 1; count < number; count++)
{
  sum *= count;
  printf("Current Sum: %d", sum);
  if(count!=number-1){
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the break word with a condition inside the loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count; 
    int number=3; // sum random value
    int sum = 1;

    for(count = 1; count <= number; count++) {
        sum *= count;
        printf("Current Sum: %d", sum);
        if(count==3) { 
            break;
        }  
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When count equals 3 the loop will end, as a consequence the printf("\n"); will not be executed in the last iteration

Comment: Better use `if(count==number)`.